# C# - How to invoke WCF callback calls from outside the service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, callback

I have a solution which runs as a service and communicates with another application via WCF.
Basically I added WCF service library and define the service contract as "CallbackContract"

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IKioskWcfCallback))]
public interface IKioskWcfService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void OpenSession();
}

public interface IKioskWcfCallback
{

    [OperationContract]
    void OnCallback();
}
```

I launch the WCF service from the main project using the class ServiceHost

```
        Wcfservice = new ServiceHost(typeof(KioskWcf.KioskWcfService));
        Wcfservice.Open();
```

From inside the WCF web service I can call the callback without any issue. I save the callback reference when the client connects and just invoke that callback later.

```
public class KioskWcfService : IKioskWcfService
{
    public static IKioskWcfCallback Callback;
    public static Timer Timer;

    public void OpenSession()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("> Session opened at {0}", DateTime.Now);
        Callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IKioskWcfCallback>();

        Timer = new Timer(3000);
        Timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        Timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Callback.OnCallback();
    }
```

Now, I would like to invoke the callback in some other part of my project but I dont know how to reference the callback of the connected client.

I saw in some answers that a method GetClients() exists but in my case VS 2015 does not offer that method.

Here my App.cfg

```
      <service name="KioskWcf.KioskWcfService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="KioskWcf.IKioskWcfService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8090/KioskWcf/KioskWcfService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would like to invoke the callback in some other part of my project**

What you can do is ,in the client application or wherever you want to call this callback ,then you have to implement the callback's interface in the client application.

Suppose **MyClient** application is the client or other project where you want to consume or call the IKioskWcfCallback ,then

```
class MyClient :KioskNamespace.IKioskWcfCallback 
{
  //control is returned from callback to here.
  public void OnCallback()
  {

  }
}
```